# Measuring 4.2V battery voltage from a 3.3V MCU

Tags: batteries, voltage-divider

I was considering using the circuit shown below to measure the battery voltage without having to drain the battery (see original post [here](https://jeelabs.org/2013/05/18/zero-power-measurement-part-2)). The MCU is an ESP32 and uses 3.3V and needs to measure the battery voltage using a voltage divider to step the voltage down from the 4.2V.

[image: Schematic]

The `BATT_SENS_EN` pin of the MCU turns the mosfet on and the `BATT_SENS` pin can read half the voltage applied at `B_OUT+`. My question is particularly around the `BATT_SENS_EN` pin — this seems like it is pulled up to 4.2V and will most certainly damage the MCU. Are there any techniques to address this issue?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: your microcontroller has an allowed current that a pin is allowed to sink when its voltage is above VCC, typically in a datasheet table under "absolute maximum ratings". You'd choose R21 much larger, usually, and especially large enough to keep that current small enough. Apropos: Making resistors larger, why are R19 and R20 10 kΩ? that feels very strong.

Comment: The original circuit has a capacitor between the enable GPIO pin and P-MOS gate. A simplistic  simulation shows that the cap will buffer the voltage difference between the battery voltage and the MCU's supply voltage.

Comment: @MarcusMüller OP has not specified electrical characteristics of the MCU ADC, but it's typical for these things to need an apparent impedance of at most ~10k. Might be able to weaken it, but not by much or else the ADC cap will be too slow to charge.

Answer (score 6):

Since you don't have a MCU that tolerates more than 3.3V on IO pins, you can add another transistor to pull the FET gate low.